Passive- voice with the continuous aspect

Rooms are painted now = the action of painting is completed now

Rooms are being painted now = the action of painting is ongoing now

The rooms are being painted everyday = the action of painting is ongoing. Although this sentence suggest something new, temporal, and short lasting. Nothing what happens everday for years or something what is planned to happen in the future everyday.

Rooms are painted everyday = I am pretty sure unlike 1 it doesn't mean that the action is completed everyday but rather that it happens but we don't know if it is always completed right?



No one says "the apple is eaten now."  Your examples are just not very good. The apple is eaten at the end of the game, not the beginning. The apple is not gone at all, You should strive for real-world sentences. is being [past participle] means now so it can't take everyday or yesterday.

There is an answer that mentions apples. You changed the question so radically the answer is now disconnected. The user says that none of the previous sentences made sense or sounded natural. Can the same observation be made with the new sentences? Not really. You should rollback the edit to how the question was originally. -1

None of these sentences is very natural. Yes, we can use the definite article to mean 'that animal/plant as a species', but not in this context. 'The apple is eaten every day/year' sounds as though you mean the same piece of fruit, which is obviously absurd. If you wanted to emphasise the popularity of the apple, you would have to say 'Apples are eaten every day'.
(1) We would say 'The apple has been eaten now.'
(2) is possible, though it would be more natural to say '[Someone] is eating the apple now'.

what about 3,4 and 5?

Read my first paragraph again!
